# DENSE_RANK with distinct columns after filter

Tags: sql-server, rank

I find myself needing to get the most recent N things accessed by each user, and I have a log table of all accesses. Something like

`CREATE TABLE [AccessLog] ([UserId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, [ThingId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, [AccessDate] DATETIME)`

So I wrote

```
SELECT [UserId], [ThingId], [SequenceNumber]
  FROM (SELECT [UserId], [ThingId], DENSE_RANK()
          OVER (PARTITION BY [UserId] ORDER BY [AccessDate] DESC) SequenceNumber
          FROM [AccessLog]
     ) [AccessLog]
 WHERE [SequenceNumber] < @N
```

This doesn't work because if the same user accessed the same thing repeatedly we get the same `[ThingId]` back up to N times rather than N distinct `[ThingIds]` back for each user.

I'm baffled how to actually do it. The table is so large that if I have to write the N cubed join like it's 2000 again (join table back on itself once to exclude duplicate copies and a second time to generate the count) it will be faster to suck in the entire table and process it in application code.

It's almost like I want

```
FOR EACH [UserId] IN (SELECT [UserId] IN [User])
    SELECT TOP (@N) [UserId], [ThingId]
      FROM [AccessLog]
     ORDER BY [AccessDate] DESC
```

But that performance is also so bad I'd to better reading the table into application code again.

Comment: To be clear, if `@N = 3` you want the top 3 unique `ThingIds` per `UserId`? If so, when there are *dupe* `ThingIds` in that top 3, which row of the dupes should be returned?...the first, the last, or any random row of the dupes?

Comment: You are correct for @N = 3 I want the top 3 thingids per userid. In fact N is constant; and the select clause makes it not matter which of the rows it got.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> You are correct for @N = 3 I want the top 3 thingids per userid. In fact N is constant; and the select clause makes it not matter which of the rows it got.

Cool, so here's the game plan. Let's group up the `AccessLog` table by `UserId` and `ThingId` so that there's only 1 unique row per, and we'll use the `MAX()` aggregate function to get the last `AccessDate` for each, so they can all be relatively compared within your window function.

Here's a query for that:

```
DECLARE @N INT = 3;

SELECT
    UserId,
    ThingId,
    SequenceRankId
FROM
(
    SELECT
        UserId,
        ThingId,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER
        (
            PARTITION BY UserId
            ORDER BY MAX(AccessDate) DESC -- Ordering by the last access of each Thing per User (MAX() is the key here)
        ) AS SequenceRankId
    FROM AccessLog
    GROUP BY UserId, ThingId -- Ensures only 1 row per ThingId per UserId
) AS AccessLogsRanked
WHERE SequenceRankId <= @N
ORDER BY UserId, SequenceRankId;
```

Comment: @Joshua Np, best of luck!